# Magento 2 default invoice not rendering css properly

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I've setup multiple magento 2 website store, but this time i have problem with invoice email template, the problem is the email template seems not rendering css because from the look of it, it shows very messy html being generated, in sales email configuration i already make sure it set to default email template, here's the email that has been sent:

[image: this is not normal default email template]

i need to make it normal like this:

[image: normal default email template]